# chrome.storage.sync does not sync across browsers and devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `chrome.storage.sync` in an extension to sync data entered in a textarea in a `popup.html`.

It stores and restores the data correctly locally but it does not sync the data across browsers.

Each browser extension has its own locally entered data available.

The following code is used to save and restore the data:

```js
// Called when the user opens popup.html
$(window).ready(
    function restore() {
        var textarea = document.querySelector("#contacts");
        chrome.storage.sync.get('contacts', function(r) {
            console.log("Contacts retrieved");
            var content = r["contacts"];
            textarea.value = content;
        });
});

// Called when user saves his changes to the textarea
$("#save-button").click(function() {
        var textarea = document.querySelector("#contacts").value;
        var save = {};
        save["contacts"] = textarea;
        // Save data using the Chrome extension storage API.
        chrome.storage.sync.set(save, function() {
            console.log("Contacts saved");
        });
        $("#confirm").text("Contacts saved.").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

In my `manifest.json` I grant permissions to `storage`:

```js
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

What is the reason for Chrome Sync not syncing across browsers and devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your extension uploaded to your Chrome Web Store account and published (or at least published to your testers)?

Cross-computer sync doesn't work on non-Web Store extensions last I checked, so you have to put it on the Chrome Web Store to test.

You also have to make sure **Extensions** is checked under `chrome://settings/syncSetup`.

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, the extension can be found in Chrome Web Store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sms-chrome/ndpcfnbbkogdnhdhgfmooinabiaakdnp/details) but only for German users since the core functionality is only working in Germany. I installed my own extension from Webstore. So not using it locally. Furthermore **Extensions** is checked under `chrome://settings/syncSetup`.

Comment: This is strange. For some reasons it is working now. Maybe Chrome Sync just needs some time before it initialises the syncing process across the devices and systems?

Comment: Go to chrome://sync and you'll be able to see if sync is working correctly and what exact data is being synced.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Google Storage API has some limitations, the number of synchronizations per minute and the weight of the items to synchronize. I found this : http://www.developer.com/lang/synchronized-storage-between-multiple-computers-with-chrome-sync.html

I hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to "方 觉" who commented on Aug 2, 2013 at 6:01.

Go to chrome://sync and you'll be able to see list of Extensions being synced and when.

[image]